# How to edit in JFreeChart the Number of minorTicks on a PeriodAxis

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a JFreeChart standard TimelineGraph. There is an Y Axis with numbers from 0 to 600, and a X Axis to show the period of time you wish to see.

I have implemented the following code:

```
protected void setupDomainAxis() {
    final long periodMillis = to.toDate().getTime() - from.toDate().getTime();
    if (periodMillis <= DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
        DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis();
        domainAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat(UserContext.getCurrentUser().getTimeFormat().getPattern()));
        domainAxis.setRange(new DateRange(from.toDate(), to.toDate()), true, true);
        domainAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.HOUR, 2));
        domainAxis.setMinorTickMarksVisible(true);
        domainAxis.setMinorTickCount(2);
        getPlot().setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
    }


    else if (periodMillis == 172799999) {

        PeriodAxis domainAxis = new PeriodAxis(null);
        PeriodAxisLabelInfo[] info = new PeriodAxisLabelInfo[1];
        info[0] = new PeriodAxisLabelInfo(Day.class,
                new SimpleDateFormat(UserContext.getCurrentUser().getDateFormat().getWeekdayPattern(), LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
        domainAxis.setLabelInfo(info);

        domainAxis.setMinorTickMarksVisible(true);
        domainAxis.setMinorTickMarkOutsideLength(1);
        domainAxis.setMinorTickCount(3);

        domainAxis.setRange(new DateRange(from.toDate(), to.toDate()), true, true);
        getPlot().setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
    }
```

}

The first part of the method works great. The difference between the first part and the second part is the type of the `domainAxis`.

As a `DateAxis` I can set the `setMinorTickCount(2);` method, but as a `PeriodAxis` I can set the visibility, the marklength, but not the number of ticks.

Anybody an idea? I don´t understand why, because both kinds of Axis inherit from `org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis` and have the `setMinorTickCount(int count)` method.

Comment: Is it possible, that there is a bug inside of the framework?